# Log events Firebase Analytics for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to implement the `Firebase Analytics for Android` and it's not working.

So far what I have done is this https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("dev", "TEST");

    // [START custom_event]
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("dev_name", "dev_name_test");
    params.putString("dev_description", "Testing log events");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("dev_test", params);
    // ....
```

Also I have disabled the `disable Instant Run`:

> To disable Instant Run: Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
>   Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run. Uncheck the
>   box next to Enable Instant Run

Any idea why is not working? I can't see anything in my firebase dashboard.

Comment: What does it mean "it is not working"? You have to wait up to 24 hours to see your events in console.

Comment: I just logged a similar question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449449/why-am-i-not-seeing-firebase-analytics-logging-in-logcat have you tried the logcat stuff I mention?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fastest way to validate that events are recorded and uploaded is to enable debug logging: [View events in the Android Studio debug log](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log)

In summary run this from command line with the device/emulator connected:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

You should see messages when you log events or set properties and when the data is uploaded.

Comment: and how do we stop these from showing after we are finished?

Comment: hi thanks, but are we still wait 24 hours to see events in web console ?

Comment: Just enable debug mode to speed this up: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Answer (score 1):

It takes around 2-4 hours in my experiences for any events to appear in the console. Also, note that the default view in the console is the past 30 days, you may want to switch this to *Today*. Something to consider also is that in the console for custom events you will only be able to view the event `dev_test` and not the strings you have added as custom parameters. You must export the events to BigQuery to view the custom parameters you have added `dev_name` abd `dev_description`. [See my similar question here which may also help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357605/android-firebase-analytics-custom-events-reporting-in-console)