# Why am I not seeing Firebase Analytics logging in logcat?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have done this according to the docs:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log)

But this is all the output I see:

```
05-25 16:45:32.992 I/FA      ( 7019): App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
05-25 16:45:32.992 I/FA      ( 7019): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
```

I am certainly logging events as I have confirmed in the debugger that I'm calling the `logEvent()` API (*and* I do see them (much later) in the web dashboard).

and if I append a bunch of garbage to my event names I see this sort of output:

```
05-25 16:53:34.703 E/FA      (14150): Name must consist of letters, digits or _ (underscores). Type, name: event, clickedwhat the heck! no!!!
```

So I know my event names are at least being validated.. but I never see any of the unmolested events getting logged as being sent or any other sort of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem on all my N preview devices. Once I installed it on a pre-N device everything worked as expected.

It seems like `adb shell setprop` isn't working on N preview 3