# Firebase custom events

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

I've a few custom events like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("my_key", "some_value");
bundle.putString("my_key2", "some_value_2");
bundle.putString("my_key3", "some_value_3");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("my_event", bundle);
```

In the Firebase console I can see the **my_event** in Events tab but I can't find the **my_key** and **some_value**. I came across some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357605/android-firebase-analytics-custom-events-reporting-in-console) where is stated that data will be available as soon as your audience reach 10 or more. Well I've reached that audience.
The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events) says:

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in
>   your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience
>   definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are
>   also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a
>   BigQuery project.

But in the Audience tab I have:
[image]

If *Filter not applicable*  how can I consult my custom event? I don't want to use BigQuery, all I want is to create custom events and consult them like I would with Google Analytics.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change these 2 predefined audience types, but you can create your own **audience type**:

This audience can either be based on an **event** or a **user property**. In your case, check event, you should see a list of predefined and custom events. Choose **my_event**, and then you get the button to add a parameter. this button allows you to further refine your query with parameter values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The information you shared is useful but I want to consult my_event bundle key pair values ("my_key", "some_value"). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately BigQuery seems to be the only way to view raw events. Maybe in a future version... Real-time database could do thejob for you:

Comment: `database.getReference("events").child("my_event").push().setValue(bundle)`. Then you'll see the parameters in the database console.

Comment: thanks for your help. If we use BigQuery I'll let you know if we succeeded. ;)