# Firebase DynamicLinks - Can i see analytics of link created by the new buildShortDynamicLink API?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using the new buildShortDynamicLink API of Firebase (And it's great).
And i see there are two methodes for the ShortDynamicLink result:

```
Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();
```

I tried to use both but still the link doesn't apear in the Firebase dashboard.
What is getPreviewLink used for anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: From the document is it saying "Gets the preview link to show the link flow chart" do you checked that?

Comment: Where exactly should i check? As i said, the link doesn't apear in the Firebase dynamic links dashboard.

Comment: This may help you https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Thanks, but i already read it all :)  I know that programmatically created link don't appear in the dashboard but i'm wondering if it's different fort the new short link, because there are created by Firebase themself and therefore can be easily added when created.

Comment: is this applicable in your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369326/1697047 ?

Comment: No, this is not releavent. Its firebase analytics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only analytics for links created in the console will show up in the console.

You can still access the analytics for your short links created via the API by using the Firebase Dynamic Links Rest API as described here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics).

The *getPreview* returns the url to a visual flowchart that helps illustrate clearly how the link will work in each context. You can use it to debug the link if you want and to visually see how it will behave in different contexts.
 Full disclosure: I work for Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is expected. Only links created **through the dashboard** will show up there.

Think about it from this perspective: when your users are creating hundreds or even thousands of links per day, it will quickly make the dashboard completely useless if they all show up there.

At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), we take the same approach by default, though we do offer a manual flag you can change on programmatically-generated links to have them show up on the dashboard if desired.